# Split a string in a linq select expression

Tags: c#, linq

The geoStartLoc holds the string in this format "54.5,44.5". I am trying to split and store the results  in lat and longitude. I am getting the following error
**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. (select statement)**

```
var data = from UberTrip in db.UberTrips
           group UberTrip by new { UberTrip.startLoc, UberTrip.geoStartLoc } 
           into startLocGroup
           select new LocationGroup() {
               startLocation = startLocGroup.Key.startLoc,
               latitude = startLocGroup.Key.geoStartLoc.Split(',').Count().ToString(),
               //longitude= startLocGroup.Key.
               countTrips = startLocGroup.Count()
           };
```

Comment: Could 'solve' it by `db.UberTrips.ToList()`, but I would suggest you write ``select new LocationGroup(startLocGroup);`` and put your logic into the constructor.

Comment: This is a schema problem in your database. It's bad to ever store delimited values in a column. You want two columns: one for geoLat, and one for geoLong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since that isn't supported by the underlying Linq to Entities you'll have to do it after you get the data but before you return the results.

This way you do the query to get the data without invoking the string split function and then modify the results into the proper format.

```
var data = from UberTrip in db.UberTrips
               group UberTrip by new { UberTrip.startLoc, UberTrip.geoStartLoc } into startLocGroup

               select new {
                   startLocation = startLocGroup.Key.startLoc,
                   geoStartLoc = startLocGroup.Key.geoStartLoc,
                   countTrips = startLocGroup.Count()
               };

               return data.Select(trip => new LocationGroup() {
                   startLocation = trip.startLocation,
                   latitude = trip.geoStartLoc.Split(',')[0],
                   longitude= trip.geoStartLoc.Split(',')[1],
                   countTrips = trip.countTrips
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: I want to upvote this, but I also want to downvote for calling .Split() twice on the same string.

Comment: This doesn't actually execute the SQL before the splits.  You need a `AsEnumerable` before the `Select`.

Comment: @juharr thought so aswell but wasnt sure

Comment: Not sure why I am getting this error  System.NotSupportedException: 'The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.' I solved this by making the data.asEnumerable.Select(....) since it L2S approach thanks this helped

Answer (score 1):

This is a schema problem in your database. It's bad to ever store delimited values in a column. You should really have two columns: one for `geoLatitude`, and one for `geoLongitude`.

But since you probably can't make that change on your own, what you'll need to do is make sure the data is pulled down to your program's code and then split it there. Right now, linq is trying to take the expression tree created by this code and convert it to an SQL query, and it can't do it for the `Split()` call because not all supported database targets have an analogous Split method available. You need to save that part for after the data is loaded to memory in your program.

To accomplish this, just retrieve the full `geoStartLoc` string (into an anonymous type if you have to), use `.ToList()` to force the query compile and retrieve all the data, and then use a `.Select()` to convert to your `LocationGroup` objects.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` is better suited for this than `ToList`.  That way you avoid an unneeded intermediate list.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get this error message you are performing a query `AsQueryable` instead of `AsEnumerable`.

The main difference is that `AsQueryable` will usually be performed in another process like a database, while `AsEnumerable` will be performed in-memory in your process.

An IEnumerable object knows how to create an `Enumerator`. An Enumerator, knows how to do two things: "Give me the first element of your sequence", and "Give me the next element of your sequence (or null if there is no next element).

If your query is `AsEnumerable` it knows can use all classes and data from your process to create the enumerator. Therefore it can call functions like String.Split.

The `AsQueryable` does not hold all data to create the enumerator, it holds an Expression and a `Provider`. The Provider knows where the query needs to be performed on (usually a database, but it can also be a json string or a web service), and it knows how to translate the `Expression` into a format that the executor understands. In your case, the `Provider` knows how to translate the `Expression` into a SQL statement suitable for your database.

Of course SQL does not know your own defined functions. Although there are a lot  of .NET functions that can be translated into SQL, not every function can. String.Split is one of them.

See: [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)

To solve your problems you could bring the queried data to local memory. This is done using the extension function [Enumerable.AsEnumerable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx). After that you can use your sequence as if it is an IEnumerable.

The disadvantage of AsEnumerable is that it brings the queried data to local memory. This would be a waste if you remove a lot of this data to create your end result. Therefore make sure that you do your AsEnumerable with not too much data.

Luckily you need the Split in your final Select, so all data you need as input of your final select is thrown away, unless you will do a Skip / Take / FirstOrDefault / etc. In that case it is better to limit your Select by doing your Skip / Take etc before AsEnumerable().

I'm more familiar with MethodSyntax.
Your query divided into smaller steps (if desired make one LINQ):

```
// still AsQueryable:
var startLocGroups = db.UberTrips
    .GroupBy(uberTrip => new {uberTip.startLoc, uberTrip.geoStartLoc)

// make asEnumerable
var localStartLocGroups = startLocGroups.AsEnumerable();

// now you can do your Select
var result = localStartLocGroups
    .Select(group => new LocationGroup()
    {
        startLocation = startLocGroup.Key.startLoc,
        latitude = group.Key.geoStartLoc.Split(',')
            .Count()
            .ToString(),
         //longitude= sgroup.Key.
         countTrips = group.Count(),
       });
```